# Enqueue script throws error in console

Tags: admin, javascript, errors, wp-enqueue-script, wordpress-version

WP version 3.9
I am editing the customizer. I have an upload field for uploading a logo.

[image]

When I try to upload I receive an error.

TypeError: wp.media.model.settings.post is undefined[image]

I tracked the problem and it is coming from this ADMIN JS which I am including.

THE ERROR WILL APPEAR EVEN IF THE JS IS EMPTY

```
function woop_admin_background_scripts() {       
 wp_enqueue_script(
        'woop-custom-background-ext-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/functions/custom-backgrounds.js',
        array( 'wp-color-picker', 'media-views' ),
        'v1.0',
        true
    );

    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'woop_admin_background_scripts' );
```

What I tried is to remove the $deps. If it is empty it works correctly.

```
        array( 'wp-color-picker', 'media-views' ), >>>> '',
```

I cannot understand what is the problem. Why it gives me JS errors because a JS is enqueued. What it will be the solution, how to solve that issue ?

Thank you

Comment: I would expect media-views is what is being pulled in that does this, but why are you trying to pull it in? Instead of asking why your code to implement X throws an error in the console, why didn't you ask "how do I implement X?"

Comment: You are right wp-color-picker', 'media-views' was the problem. I just stopped loading the file on all screens